# How to generate random blobs?

Tags: random, 3d, shapes, voxel

I would like to generate random shapes in 3D.  I want the shapes to be blobs, essentially what could be obtained by taking a sphere and distorting it to be less regularly shaped but still mostly compact.  Think taking a ball of clay and pinching or pushing and pulling it slightly.  The surface curvature or scale of irregularities on the surface should be controllable using some kind of parameter.  I would like the output to be a volume consisting of voxels (1 for inside and 0 for outside), although a surface which can be converted to a volume is also ok.

I've looked at Gaussian random spheres, which are superpositions of spherical harmonics.  I couldn't quite figure out the math for these, and there is no sample code anywhere.  Also, they can't generate any shape which has an overhang (ie, where a ray from the center of the sphere intersects the surface more than once).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 3D [metaballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaballs).

Randomly generate a set of points in 3D. 5 or less should work but you can vary this.

For each voxel, compute the inverse distance (or some other function of the voxel and point co-ordinates) to each of the points and sum them. If the sum is equal to or greater than a threshold value, it's in the blob, if it's less than it then it's outside.

You can vary the threshold value and optionally give each point a different random weight (which can be negative). Roughly speaking you want the threshold distances from each point to overlap, or else you'll just have a bunch of separate spheres.

Answer (score 1):

I use libnoise ...
http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/

It's a general purpose noise library deisgned for generating perlin / simplex or other types of "seudo random" data.

the "seudo" means that it's seeded so we can recompute the exact same data by supplying the same seed value when we being, it's for things like virtual worlds of procedurally generating textures.

It could easily be configured to generate the sort of thing you want.